# Ignore empty form values on update using laravl5

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Is there anyway to remove empty form value form request->all() method ?
This is what i am trying to do on update,In other words only post filled form values.

```
 $data = request()->except(['_token','id']);

 DB::table($table)->where('id',$id)->update($data);
```

Note:I have dynamically generated columns so i think i can't use those column in except parameters's list.

This updates all the column of the row,but all i want to update only those column that's value is filled  and for the remaining columns/fields keep the same old value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
// All posted data except token and id
$data = request()->except(['_token','id']);

// Remove empty array values from the data
$result = array_filter($data);

// update record
DB::table($table)->where('id', $arr)->update($result);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
// app/controllers/GiftsController.php

public function update($id)
{
    // Grab all the input passed in
    $data = Input::all();

    // Use Eloquent to grab the gift record that we want to update,
    // referenced by the ID passed to the REST endpoint
    $gift = Gift::find($id);

    // Call fill on the gift and pass in the data
    $gift->fill($data);

    $gift->save();
}
```

I found this piece of code in [this tutorial](https://ryanchenkie.com/laravel-put-requests) and works like charm. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. This is something I was looking for.